# Como esconder um menu drawer arrastando?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, webview

Então estou começando a desenvolver sites e fiz um menu drawer estilo o do google play pra versão mobile do site só que ele não esconde quando arrasto ele pro lado alguém sabe um jeito de fazer essa interação ?

Comment: Você pode postar o código?

Answer (score 1):

É preciso utilizar o jquery mobile para realizar esse menu, pois nativo, não tem como captar a função `swipeleft` e `swiperight`

O link para baixar o jquery mobile é: http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ e você pode escolher apenas as funções que deseja baixar, no caso, as funções de Touch. Basta selecionar o checkbox com essa opção que ele vai selecionar todas as suas dependências.

Após fazer isso, aplique o seguinte código:

```
//para abrir o menu    
$(window).on("swiperight",function(e){
  //estilo do menu aberto
});

//para fechar o menu    
$(window).on("swipeleft",function(e){
  //estilo do menu fechado
});
```

Comment: Legal mais ele não acompanha o touch? tipo o do google play se vc para na metade do evento, ele para junto, sabe como fazer?

Comment: wDrik, conseguiu encontrar alguma soluçao que faz oq deseja? Estou com essa duvida tambem